# Puedo utilizar el mismo controlador para registrar dos tipos de personas?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Bueno tengo un formulario en php tengo un select en el cual elijo si el tipo de cliente a registrar es natural o jurídico, al seleccionar cual quiera de los dos se muestra el formulario correspondiente. El problema es que para registrar cada tipo cliente estoy haciendo uso de dos controladores, lo cual no estoy seguro de que sea lo correcto.

**Base de datos.**
[image: Base de datos]

**Controlador Cliente Natural**

```
public function store(ClientesFormRequest $request)
{
    if ($request) {
      try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
          $persona_natural = new Persona_natural;
          $persona_natural->telefono = $request->get('telefono');
          $persona_natural->cedula = $request->get('cedula');
          $persona_natural->direccion = $request->get('direccion');
          $persona_natural->nombre = $request->get('nombre');
          $persona_natural->save();

          $cliente = new Cliente;
          $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Bogota');
          $cliente->fecha_inscripcion = $mytime->toDateTimeString();
          $cliente->persona_natural_idpersona_natural = $persona_natural->idpersona_natural;
          $cliente->estado = 'Activo';
          $cliente->save();
        DB::commit();
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        db::rollback();
      }

      return redirect::to('cliente/natural');
    }
}
```

**Controlador Cliente Juridico**

```
public function store(JuridicosFormRequest $request)
    {
      if ($request) {
        try {
          DB::beginTransaction();
            $juridico = new Persona_juridico;
            $juridico->rason_social = $request->get('rason_social');
            $juridico->ruc = $request->get('ruc');
            $juridico->tipo_entidad = $request->get('tipo_entidad');
            $juridico->correo_electronico = $request->get('correo_electronico');
            $juridico->persona_natural_idpersona_natural = $request->get('persona_natural_idpersona_natural');
            $juridico->save();

            $cliente = new Cliente;
            $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Bogota');
            $cliente->fecha_inscripcion = $mytime->toDateTimeString();
            $cliente->juridico_idjuridico = $juridico->idjuridico;
            $cliente->estado = 'Activo';
            $cliente->save();


          DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          db::rollback();
        }

        return redirect::to('cliente/natural');
      }
    }
```

**Requests.**
Cliente natural

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'telefono'=>'max:20',
            'cedula'=>'required|max:10',
            'direccion'=>'required|max:200',
            'nombre'=>'required|max:50'
        ];
    }
```

Cliente juridico

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'rason_social',
            'ruc',
            'tipo_entidad',
            'correo_electronico',
            'persona_natural_idpersona_natural'
        ];
    }
```

A mi modo de ver creo que lo correcto seria colocar un if que me permita validar el tipo de cliente mediante el foreingKey que voy a registrar en la tabla **cliente**, es decir si lo que recibe mi controlador es un **jurídico_idjuridico**, entonces ingreso la información en la tabla **jurídico**, y si es lo que recibe es **persona_natural_idpersona_natural** entonces la inserción debería realizarse en la tabla persona_natural, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo. debería validar eso con php??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me atrevo a decir que esta pregunta obtiene respuestas que se basan en opiniones, aún así voy a responderla para guiar un poco y mejorar las prácticas de la persona que pregunta:

1. Si tienes al menos dos tipos de clientes, asumo que tienes un trait `ClienteController` que hace las tareas comunes entre ambos tipos de clientes y de este ambos clientes heredan, además de tener una interface implementada para respetar los métodos que deben tener ambos clientes.
2. No debe ser responsabilidad del controlador tener que lidiar con la base de datos y modelos, su función es simplemente delegar esta función a un servicio o a un repositorio.
3. Utilizar `new Algo` va en contra de las buenas prácticas de Laravel y de la programación "moderna". Esto genera dependencias innecesarias y hace más dificil de mantener y probar el código, para eso existe la inyección de dependencias, tal y como lo haces con el Request.

---

Yo utilizaría un solo Request para validar ambos formularios, y utilizaría un solo método `store()`, y a partir de ahí llamaría al repositorio correspondiente para que almacene los datos.

Comment: me surgen mas preguntas ....entonses para entender que son los `traits`, `inyección de dependencias` y como funcionan debo investigar tutoriales de php??

Comment: En teoría todo eso debes saberlo antes de utilizar Laravel o cualquier otro framework.

Comment: entiendo gracias

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera es unificar en un controller. Lo pasas un parámetro que indique el tipo de cliente. Luego al querer insertar en una tabla o otra, utilizar el tipo de cliente que habías recibido. Ejemplo:

```
$tipo = $request->get('rason_social');
if($tipo == 'natural'){
    // Insertar en tabla persona_natural.
}else {
     // Insertar en tabla juridico
}
```

El código anterior es solo una idea para que se entienda.

En cuanto a la validación te conviene siempre hacer para no insertar cualquier valor en tu tabla. Y eso deberías de controlar. Yo lo hago en ambos lados (cliente (navegador web) y servidor), pero ya depende de vos. Pero si es recomendable y necesario que valides por lo menos en el lado del servidor. En tu caso en el php.

Comment: amigo ya agrege los request al post, tengo dos requests, si los dos los compagino en uno solo no va funcionar pues por que los atributos que el uno necesita el otro no y me va a pedir que ingrese los datos que faltan

Comment: @jeancarlos733 si tenes dos request, mandalo dos. Yo no utilizo laravel, pero debería de haber la manera de envía dos parámetros o dos request

Comment: No se pueden enviar dos Request en Laravel al mismo método, es como si solicitaras dos páginas web distintas.

Comment: @Shaz pero si se puede usar crear manualmente validadores. Encontré un ejemplo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311109/laravel-5-validate-multiple-request-do-all-requests-at-the-same-time

Comment: Eso no es más que hacer las validaciones manualmente en el controlador, lo cual no aconsejo salvo en casos en los que sea estrictamente necesario, en cierta forma estarías desaprovechando algunas features del Request, de hecho si lees el comentario del OP en esa respuesta, notarás que tampoco lo convence.

Comment: @Shaz ok. muchas gracias